# Replacing lines of a text file with powershell, based on lines of a different text file

Tags: file, powershell, text, replace, edit

So i have 2 files that have the same style of listed content- Font ID, Font Def, and a Timestamp. I want to take a 2nd file of new fonts, and replace the lines of the first file that have matching font IDs---using powershell(no database which would be massively easier).

File2 text line = [FontIDA01] 5,5,5,5, randomtext, 11/10/2001 
should replace the line of File1 where [FontIDA01] matches up, and replace the 5,5,5,5 with 6,6,6,6, and the date with the date on that line.

```
$content = Get-Content $fileSelected #(path chosen by user)
$masterContent = Get-Content $masterContentPath #(hardcoded path)
foreach($line in content)
{
   $fontID = $line.SubString($startFontID, $endFontID)#this just sets font id = 23jkK instead of [23jkK]
   foreach($masterLine in $masterContent)
   {
      if ($masterLine.Contains($fontID))
      {
         $masterContent -replace $masterLine, $line where-Object{$_.Name -contains $fontID} | Set-Content $masterContent -raw 
      }
   }
}
```

Am I even close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect the new data in a dictionary and use it for replacements:

```
# get new data in a dictionary
$newData = @{}
Get-Content 2.txt | %{
    $parts = $_ -split ' '
    $newData[$parts[0]] = @{numbers=$parts[1]; date=$parts[3]}
}

#patch original data using the new data dictionary
Get-Content 1.txt | %{
    $parts = $_ -split ' '
    $id = $parts[0]
    $new = $newData[$id]
    if ($new) {
        $id, $new.numbers, $parts[2], $new.date -join ' '
    } else {
        $_
    }
} | Out-File 3.txt -Encoding utf8
```

This code is assuming the fields are separated by spaces, so if it's not the case you'll have to use other methods of extracting the parts like `Select-String` or regexp matching: `if ($_ -match '(.+?) ([\d,]+) and so on') { $id = $matches[0] }`.

Comment: Any chance you have an answer that is more beginner level? I don't have any clue what your code is doing

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I thought about your code. Silly me, believing my code is self-explanatory... Well, someone will post a better answer, hopefully. If it's any help, the code processes each file line by line using `|` piping.